# Guessing is a four-letter word

Tags: riddle, science, computer-science

*This is my first riddle here — I hope it's not too easy.*

> I killed my brother a long time ago,
>
> And if I'm right, running fast won't help you.
>
> My relatives are weaker, shorter;
>
> But I may be wrong alone.

**Hint:**

> All I'm saying is, it's hard to decide.

**Edit:** a hint/spoiler.

> The first line is to be taken literally (i.e., actual murder, although pertaining to mythological or legendary characters).

Comment: And if I'm right, running fast won't help you. What's this line justify?

Comment: @numberknot What do you mean? It's part of the puzzle. (What specifically would you like to know?)

Comment: Got it.........

Comment: With regard to the votes to close: I added a hint (and a tag). Does it look better now?

Comment: Definitely some improvement. But what does "literally, in a mythological sense" mean?

Comment: @AE I meant it as Romulus-kind, with a legendary or mythological character committing fratricide.

Comment: "Figuratively" might be a better word choice  than "literally" then. I retracted my close vote though.

Comment: @AE I tried to make it more explicit. "Figuratively" may have put people on the wrong track -- the line refers to a "real" murder, even though it may not be for actual people. (It's *not* a figure of speech or metaphor, as [e.g. this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptmM-m7Cl8U))

Comment: Revised hint is definitely bette! ;)

Comment: @AE by the way, how does it usually work -- after a while, should I give more hints? The solution?

Comment: People sometimes give more hints over time - ideally the whole thing should be unambiguously solvable without recourse to the hints though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat partial answer...

Maybe it is

> Seth

I killed my brother a long time ago

> Seth killed Osiris, his brother, in Egyptian Mythology.

If I am right, running fast won't help you

> Strong exponential time hypothesis (SETH). If this hypothesis is right, there cannot be algorithms such that k-SAT problems in Computer Science can be solved in subexponential time. So a computer running fast would not make much difference.

My relatives are weaker, shorter

> SETH is a stronger form of Exponential Time Hypothesis. This could be related to Seth, the deity too, I guess.

But I may be wrong alone

> SETH implies ETH. So if ETH is false so is SETH.

Note:

> I did not know of SETH before this riddle so I might have made mistakes or missed stuff on the computer science part.

Comment: This is it! The last two clues are (very slightly) off, but that's the gist.

Comment: In particular: the two relatives are [ETH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis)  (Exponential-Time Hypothesis) and SH (Satisfiability Hypothesis), both weaker conjectures than SETH (and shorter: 3 and 2 letters only). In particular, they might both hold, while SETH is proven false. As for the hint... it's all about the hardness of deciding satisfiability of a formula.

Answer (score 7):

Are you planet

> MARS

I killed my brother a long time ago,

> Phaeton is the hypothetical planet to have existed between the orbits of Mars and Jupiter whose destruction supposedly led to the formation of the asteroid belt

And if I'm right, running fast won't help you.

> you would not escape from mars gravity by running fast on earth.

My relatives are weaker, shorter

> Mars has two moons, Phobos and Deimos which are relatively shorter and weak compared to mars.

But I may be wrong alone.

> Mars doen't stays in its orbit if it were alone in the solar system.

And

> all of these facts are hard to decide

Comment: Good thinking, but not the answer I have in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution might be

> fact.

**Explanation:**

I killed my brother a long time ago:

> The brother that was killed would be believe, as facts kill believes, either by turning them into knowledge, or by disproving them. Starting to disprove believes by facts indeed started a long time ago, in Greek philosophy.

And if I'm right, running fast won't help you:

> You cannot escape the hard facts (I take "running fast" as metaphorical here, like running from the truth).

My relatives are weaker, shorter:

> Relatives might be believe, hypothesis, assumption, possibility — all are weaker than a fact, as they are less certain. I have no idea how "shorter" fits in, though.

But I may be wrong alone:

> A fact can in general only be decided in a context. For example "it is raining" may be true or false, depending on whether you are saying it on a rainy day or on a sunny day.

Hint:

> Many facts are hard to decide.

**Edit:**

Additional evidence:

> The riddle has the science tag. Science is all about facts.

Comment: There are good points, but this is not the answer. I added a tag (found out about it), this may help.

Answer (score 2):

It could be

> Cain

I killed my brother a long time ago,

> Cain killed Abel in the bible story.

The other lines I'm not 100% sure about, but the title and tags suggest

> guessing a password, which is what the [Cain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cain_and_Abel_(software)) software by Microsoft does.

Comment: That an interesting connection (I didn't know about that software), but not what I am looking for.